# Django doesn't commit changes to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, nginx, gunicorn

My web-app is deployed on two different VPS on different subnets, one for Django and the other for database.
the problem is that whenever i send a request to app-server it takes about 10 second to get response (waiting time) and as I noticed, this time is just for connecting to database-server (meking query). i have no idea how to fix it , in Django database setting, i set the 'CONN_MAX_AGE' parameter to **None** and now the response time is OK! but Django doesn't commit any change that i make on database and as you restart the app server all the changes rolls back! does anyone has an idea about?

thanks

Comment: Can you included your `DATABASES` configuration from your settings (remove the host, username, and password)?

Comment: `all the changes rolls back` - so those changes actually existed in the database? Otherwise where were they rolled back from? `whenever i send a request to server it takes about 10 second to get response` - which server is that? MySQL or Django app/gunicorn? Who is slow?